# Is my local variable getting overwritten to garbage?

Tags: fortran

If I call my function like this:

```
t = calcMonth(month)
```

and the corresponding function is

```
real function calcMonth(m)  
real b, m  
b = 10  
calcMonth = b*m
```

Does my variable `m` get overwritten to garbage value?

Comment: no, why would you think so?

Comment: 'm' will have the value of whatever you pass to the function.

Comment: i thought by declaring the variable 'm' locally it gets rid of the passed value of 'm'

Comment: That would be a good addition to the question text.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your comment

> i thought by declaring the variable 'm' locally it gets rid of the passed value of 'm'

When you say (cut down for clarity)

```
real function calcMonth(m)
  real m
end function
```

you are not declaring a local variable `m` in the function.  Instead you are declaring the type of the dummy argument `m`.  Indeed, doing this declaration is the only sane way to declare types and attributes of dummy arguments.  [Discussion of sanity outside the scope of this answer.]

Whilst reusing an identifier for a local variable can obscure other externally defined objects, it simply isn't allowed for dummy arguments.

I'd be very scared of a language tutorial which didn't make these features clear, but I'll speculate as to why there may be some confusion.

It may be that when one has

```
real function calcMonth(m)
  calcMonth = 10*m  ! Oh look, we are using the dummy m
end function
```

this looks very different from

```
real function calcMonth(m)
  real m            ! Hmmm, a local m
  calcMonth = 10*m  ! Oh noes, which m am I using?
end function
```

These are potentially different, but the only difference is that in the first `m` - the dummy argument - is being *implicitly* typed, in the second `m` - still the dummy argument - is being *explicitly* typed.  [With the default implicit typing rules `m` would be integer, so this is the potential difference alluded to before.]

Some languages allow one to specify types and attributes (or equivalent) like

```
real function calcMonth(integer m)
```

but Fortran isn't one of those.  Crucially, also, the type of the dummy argument doesn't come from the actual argument.

```
integer month
call calcMonth(month)
end

real function calcMonth(m)
  real m
  calcMonth = 10*m  ! Still the dummy m
end function
```

is *still* not declaring a local variable `m` - with the thought that the dummy `m` is previously declared an integer, or somehow is the actual argument `month`, and so the type mismatch means it must be a new variable - and most likely at run-time something unwanted will happen.